# Windows store app access file system

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-explorer, system.io.file

I'm developing a Windows store app and need to display files in user computer like in file explorer. Everywhere it says windows store apps only access "library" files and not other locations on the hard drives of PC. And I don't mean something like FileOpenPicker, I want to show file on may application like explorer.

What is the library I should use? System.IO class missing those methods on store apps. I know it is possible. Cos I have seen many applications in store has done that. Few examples are

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/file-browser/9wzdncrfj29m
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/my-explorer/9wzdncrfj0lm

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Apps like the ones you mention typically use a [FolderPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) to let the user pick the root of the file system and then remember that permission in a [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx) for later use.

Your research was correct: apps cannot get general access to the file system. APps can declare access to the libraries, and app have automatic access to their local data, but anywhere else requires user permission via a picker or equivalent. See [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt188700.aspx) on MSDN.